# How to change default tab-indentation width?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Is there a way to change default width of indentation when pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> key? I know about the thing on top of the page where I can change them manually, but is there a way to change the width for all future "tabs" in the document?

Comment: I don't even remember what I was asking about a year ago, but moving the indentation slider thing on the ruler can solve this, so this is my accepted answer :p

Comment: Ten years and apparently it hasn't been solved yet. I just wanted my tab key to add 4 spaces, instead of 12 in Google Docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signs are this is not possible [eg](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/googledocuments/10/print) with tabbing set at 1/2" and not configurable without use of the thing at the top of the page (ie 'ruler'!) though there are various ways to step 1/2" at a time.

Comment: How does this answer the questions?